# gulp watch scss not outputting css folder

Tags: css, node.js, sass, gulp, gulp-watch

Hi I'm new to gulp and I have installed nodejs and gulp now I'm trying compile my .scss file which is successfully being watched using "gulp watch" however its not outputting css.

node -v: 0.12.4
gulp -v: 3.9.0

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var sass = require('gulp-ruby-sass');
var sass = require('gulp-sass');
var minifyCSS = require('gulp-minify-css');
var rename = require('gulp-rename');

gulp.task('scss', function () {
    gulp.src('scss/*.scss')
        .pipe(sass({
            outputStyle: 'nested',
            includePaths: ['scss', 'bower_components/meyer-reset/stylesheets']
        }))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('css'))
        .pipe(minifyCSS())
        .pipe(rename({suffix: '.min'}))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('css'));
});

gulp.task('watch', function () {
    gulp.watch('scss/*.scss', ['scss']);
});

gulp.task('default', ['scss']);
```

package.json

```
{
  "devDependencies": {
    "gulp": "^3.9.0",
    "gulp-debug": "^2.0.1",
    "gulp-minify-css": "^1.1.1",
    "gulp-rename": "^1.2.2",
    "gulp-sass": "^1.3.3"
  }
}
```

Comment: Not sure it's related but i don't think you need to write '.pipe(gulp.dest('css'))' twice, you only need this in the end.

Comment: I removed the other one and its still not outputting anything.

Comment: To try to pinpoint the problem it's useful to remove all non-essentials. I'd remove `.pipe(minifyCSS()).pipe(rename({suffix: '.min'}))` while working on this issue, just in case - and even try to make it work directly (by running `gulp scss` task rather than `gulp watch`)

Comment: you have 2 require statements assigned to the variable `sass` pick one.